# How can I easily show difference between Current Assets and Current Liabilities in Gnucash?

Tags: gnucash

So I have a subaccount of Liabilities named "Current Liabilities" and I'd like to have an easy access to the value of `[Current Assets - Current Liabilities]` (kind of my personal "Working Capital").

I tried several reports, but without success. For example, it's possible to select desired accounts in the "Assets & Liabilities / Balance Sheet" report, but it doesn't display difference between Assets and Liabilities.

It seems to be a trivial problem, but I can't find a good solution so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a "Balance Sheet" report
2. Edit the report options
3. Click on the "Accounts" tab
4. Click the Asset account(s) you want displayed
5. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click the Liability account(s) you would like displayed
6. Press "Apply" or "OK".

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reacting. Yes, I tried this approach, and it does let me see my "Current Assets" and my "Current Liabilities". Unfortunately, what it doesn't let me see is the difference between them. 
And I just want to see my "Working Capital" (Current Assets - Current Liabilities) without having to calculate it by hand.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think I can help you there without editing the report. You can suggest that be added to the report (although your suggestion would be taken much more seriously if it was attended with a patch!) either in the mailing list, or, if you're lucky, on IRC.